# Try to display calendar list from Google API using Java Script

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, calendar

I have some troubles to display list of accesible calendar from Google Calendar via Google API. I use JavaScript and AJAX.

What methods do I need to use?
I found only event`s related methods, but not for display description of calendar.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any sample code of what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 8):

To get a basic working model you can follow the quickstart example on the [calendar API site](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js)

The example has a function called listUpcomingEvents() to get events on the "primary" calendar. To get the list of calendars use the following method:

```
function listCalendars()
{
     var request = gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list();

     request.execute(function(resp){
             var calendars = resp.items;
             console.log(calendars);
     });
}
```

Comment: Where did you find documentation on `gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list`? The [reference docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list) only shows Java, Python, PHP and Ruby and the [JS Docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs) make no mention of Calendar.

Comment: really want to know where you found the documentation about this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code I just wrote:

```
kb.loadAsync('https://apis.google.com/js/client.js', 'onload', 'gapi').then(gapi => {
    gapi.auth.authorize({
        client_id: __GOOGLE_CALENDAR_API_KEY__,
        scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
        immediate: true,
    }, authResult => {
        if(authResult && !authResult.error) {
            gapi.client.load('calendar','v3', () => {
                gapi.client.calendar.calendarList.list({
                    maxResults: 250,
                    minAccessRole: 'writer',
                }).execute(calendarListResponse => {
                    let calendars = calendarListResponse.items;
                    console.log(calendars.map(cal => cal.summary));
                });
            });
        } else {
            console.log('unauthorized');
        }
    });
});
```

`kb.loadAsync` is a helper function I wrote; looks like this:

```
/**
 * Helps load Google APIs asynchronously.
 *
 * @param {string} source
 * @param {string} callbackParam
 * @param {string=} globalName
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
export function loadAsync(source, callbackParam, globalName) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        let callbackFunc = Math.random().toString(36);

        window[callbackFunc] = () => {
            resolve(window[globalName]);
            delete window[callbackFunc];
        };

        let sep = source.includes('?') ? '&' : '?';
        $script(`${source}${sep}${encodeURIComponent(callbackParam)}=${encodeURIComponent(callbackFunc)}`);
    });
}
```

It uses [scriptjs](https://github.com/ded/script.js/). Unfortunately scriptjs' callback fires too early -- Google loads some more junk after client.js has downloaded, so it isn't quite ready to run even after it's "ready"! You have to use Google's `onload` parameter.

You don't need all those dependencies if you just to use a [bunch of `<script>` tags](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js), but I prefer me some async functions.